# Turning this list into a vector of sets

Tags: clojure

Does anyone have an idea how to convert this list of vectors into a vector of sets?

```
([#{2}] [#{1 2 3 4}] [#{5}] [#{3}])
```

result should be

```
[#{2} #{1 2 3 4} #{5} #{3}]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you would describe what you have attempted so far and what you're results were. Tip: the answer will involve `vec`.

Comment: I've tried `flatten`, though that wont do much but convert the vectors to list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sets are just *elements* of the vectors.

So, one way is to iterate (`map`) over the list of vectors and pick the `first` element of each vector (i.e. the set). This will build a list of these sets that you can then convert to a vector:

```
user=> (vec (map first '([#{2}] [#{1 4 3 2}] [#{5}] [#{3}])))
[#{2} #{1 4 3 2} #{5} #{3}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Multiple ways to accomplish this. It depends on your needs what approach you use:

```
(def data '([#{2}] [#{1 2 3 4}] [#{5}] [#{3}]))

;; If you have a list of single element lists:
(mapv first data) ;; => [#{2} #{1 2 3 4} #{5} #{3}]

;; If you have a list of multiple element lists:
(vec (apply concat data)) ;; => [#{2} #{1 2 3 4} #{5} #{3}]

;; If you also want to handle multiple levels of nesting:
(vec (flatten data)) ;; => [#{2} #{1 2 3 4} #{5} #{3}]

;; If you ..;
(transduce (map first) conj data) ;; => [#{2} #{1 2 3 4} #{5} #{3}]
```

Answer (score 4):

A way I haven't seen suggested is using `into` and `cat`.

```
(def data '([#{2}] [#{1 2 3 4}] [#{5}] [#{3}]))
(into [] cat data) => [#{2} #{1 4 3 2} #{5} #{3}]
```